# Python programming - File rotation

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to the Python, and below is my requirement:
We have three files in the RAM (i.e., under /tmp directory) in a device.
With help of psutil, I will calculate the CPU percentage in 3 different time intervals (secs, mins and hours) and logged all the CPU usage in the 3 different files. Till now, I can able to execute and got the expected output.

**Problem statement:**
The problem am facing is, I need to rotate the files whenever it gets 60 entries so that we will not occupy the much memory of the device. ie., when 61st entry comes in, I need to pop the 1 entry from the files and goes on.

Can anyone please help on this??

Below is the working code for creating a file in the RAM:

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
import psutil 

while True: 
    for x in range( 1 ): 
        for y in range( 3 ): 
            for z in range( 3 ): 
                file = open( '/tmp/cpu_sec.txt', 'a' )
                file.write( str( psutil.cpu_percent( interval=1 ) ) + '\n' )
                file.close() 
            file = open( '/tmp/cpu_min.txt', 'a' )   
            file.write( str( psutil.cpu_percent( interval=1 ) ) + '\n' ) 
            file.close() 
        file = open( '/tmp/cpu_hr.txt', 'a' )         
        file.write( str( psutil.cpu_percent( interval=1 ) ) + '\n' ) 
        file.close()
```

Comment: Can you share your thought on how to solve this. What did you try up to now? Can you provide a minimum working example of what is working up to now?

Comment: Below is the working code for creating a file in the RAM:

#! /usr/bin/python
import psutil
while True:
for x in range(1):
    for y in range(3):
        for z in range(3):
            file = open('/tmp/cpu_sec.txt','a')
            file.write(str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)) + '\n')
            file.close()
        file = open('/tmp/cpu_min.txt','a')
        file.write(str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)) + '\n')
        file.close()
    file = open('/tmp/cpu_hr.txt','a')
    file.write(str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)) + '\n')
    file.close()

Comment: My thought is to pop the first element in the file when a 61st entry comes in.
Normally we have ring/circular buffer to do the same. But in file how can we do that.?

Comment: Looks like Linux, you might call awk from within python.

Comment: Yeah. I think awk will segregate the contents but will this remove the content and replace the new one

Comment: BTW are we only talking about 60 values per file? would it be a problem to keep it in RAM all the time?

Comment: Yes.. we should not add the entries more than 60, since our script will run on an infinite loop, it would occupy more memory if we didn't restricted to a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is very small, my first idea would be to make the rotation in memory and write the full data every time, i.e. overwriting the file. You then can set the writing period different from the array update period.

The basic idea would look like:

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.zeros(20)
print myArray 

for i in range(10):
    myArray= np.append( np.delete ( myArray, 0 ), i)
    print myArray
```

substituting the `i` with the cpu data and the `print` with, e.g., `numpy.savetxt()`

Another idea is actually usind `sed` instead of `awk`. Introducing line numbers you could do something like this:

```
from psutil import cpu_percent as cp
from time import  time
import subprocess

startTime = time()

linenumber = 0
with open("tmpdata.txt", "w", 0) as fPntr:
    for i in range( 20 ):
        print i
        fPntr.write( str(linenumber) + ' ' + '{:1.2f}'.format( time() - startTime) + ' ' + str( cp( interval=1 ) ) + '\n' )
        linenumber +=1

for i in range( 120 ):
    print i
    linenumber = ( linenumber +1 ) % 20
    sedString = 's/^{} .*/{}/'.format(linenumber, str(linenumber) + ' ' + '{:1.2f}'.format( time() - startTime) + ' ' + str( cp( interval=1 ) ) )
    subprocess.call( ['sed','-i',  sedString, 'tmpdata.txt' ] )
```

I introduced the time to check that it is overwriting correctly. I use only 20 entries as I did not want to wait that long.

The third thing would be to read the file in python make the rotation and rewrite, but I do not see the point. I guess the first option would be much better than that. Anyhow, it would look something like:

```
myArray = np.zeros(20, dtype=np.int8)
np.savetxt( 'np_tmp.txt', myArray, fmt='%d' )

for i in range(10):
    np.savetxt( 'np_tmp.txt',  np.append( np.delete ( np.loadtxt( 'np_tmp.txt', dtype=np.int8 ),0 ), i ), fmt='%d' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..I will try your inputs and share the results